# Problem of Json parse when i send an body object from Flutter to node.js while it works perfect with postman

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a function in node.js and MySQL that works very fine , i have an object json of a club that contains a list of players.
So i created a function of node.js that takes this object and insert it
I did a test with postman and everything working perfect!

here the json object that works perfect in postman:

```
 {
     "userid": 41,
    "name": "fc dhya club",
    "price": 11,
    "players": [
        {
            "id":1,
            "firstname":"aaaaaaa",
            "lastname":"ee",
            "position":"df",
            "price":12.1,
            "appearences":2,
            "goals":1,
            "assists":1,
            "cleansheets":1,
            "redcards":1,
            "yellowcards":1,
            "image":"qq"
        },
  {
            "id":2,
            "firstname":"aabbbbbbbbbbb",
            "lastname":"ee",
            "position":"df",
            "price":12.1,
            "appearences":2,
            "goals":1,
            "assists":1,
            "cleansheets":1,
            "redcards":1,
            "yellowcards":1,
            "image":"qq"
        }
    ]
     }
```

Here a screen capture that shows that it works perfect in Postman:
[image]

and it works perfect when i send the request

but my problem is in flutter is that i wanted to send this structure of json to node.js so i created a model in dart that is called CLubJson:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final clubJson = clubJsonFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

ClubJson clubJsonFromJson(String str) => ClubJson.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String clubJsonToJson(ClubJson data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ClubJson {
  ClubJson({
    this.userid,
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.players,
  });

  int userid;
  String name;
  double price;
  List<Player> players;

  factory ClubJson.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ClubJson(
    userid: json["userid"],
    name: json["name"],
    price: json["price"],
    players: List<Player>.from(json["players"].map((x) => Player.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "userid": userid,
    "name": name,
    "price": price,
    "players": List<dynamic>.from(players.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Player {
  Player({
    this.id,
    this.firstname,
    this.lastname,
    this.position,
    this.price,
    this.appearences,
    this.goals,
    this.assists,
    this.cleansheets,
    this.redcards,
    this.yellowcards,
    this.image,
  });

  int id;
  String firstname;
  String lastname;
  String position;
  double price;
  int appearences;
  int goals;
  int assists;
  int cleansheets;
  int redcards;
  int yellowcards;
  String image;

  factory Player.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Player(
    id: json["id"],
    firstname: json["firstname"],
    lastname: json["lastname"],
    position: json["position"],
    price: json["price"].toDouble(),
    appearences: json["appearences"],
    goals: json["goals"],
    assists: json["assists"],
    cleansheets: json["cleansheets"],
    redcards: json["redcards"],
    yellowcards: json["yellowcards"],
    image: json["image"]
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "firstname": firstname,
    "lastname": lastname,
    "position": position,
    "price": price,
    "appearences": appearences,
    "goals": goals,
    "assists": assists,
    "cleansheets": cleansheets,
    "redcards": redcards,
    "yellowcards": yellowcards,
    "image": image
  };
}
```

and then i created a post method for this object

```
PostRequest() async {
// set up POST request arguments
    final url = Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.16:3000/api/questions/addQuestion');
    Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
    ClubJson club = ClubJson(userid: 1, name: "dsds", price: 55.2,players: [Player(id:1,firstname:"d",lastname:"ds",position:"ez",price: 5.2,appearences:1,goals:1,assists:1,cleansheets:1,yellowcards:1,redcards:2,image:"dsd")] );
    // for(var item in widget.selectedPlayers){
    //   club.players.add(Player(id:item.playerID,firstname:item.firstName,lastname:item.lastName,position:item.position,price:item.price,appearences:item.appearances,goals:item.goals,assists:item.assists,cleansheets:item.cleanSheets,redcards:item.redCards,yellowcards:item.yellowCards,image:item.image));
    // }

    String json = club.toJson().toString();
    print(club.name);
    print(club.price);
    for(var item in club.players){
      print(item.price);
    }

    // make POST request
    Response response = await post(url, headers: headers, body: json);
    // check the status code for the result
    int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    // this API passes back the id of the new item added to the body
    String body = response.body;

    // var res = jsonDecode(response.body);
    // if(res == "success"){
    //
    //   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>BottomNavBarV2(),),);
   return response;
  }
```

***Tip:***  My goals is that this function will generate an identical json to the json that i used by postman on the top

***After execution*** I have got an error of Json Parse in node.js which means that the Json i sent by Flutter is different or mal formed and node.js could not parse it

***My Goal*** is to make my body object identical to the Json of Posman that works perfect

Here a screen capture after the execution in Flutter

[image]

Comment: Try changing `String json = club.toJson().toString();` to `String json = jsonEncode(club.toJson());`

Comment: don't club.toJson() do the job?

Comment: a variable of type JsonEncode can' be assigned to type String

Comment: `toJson` only converts it from a `Club` object, into a `Map<String, dynamic>`, but it's still not enough for NodeJs to recognize it's parameters. Change it to `var json = jsonEncode(club.toJson());` and run your function.

Comment: jsonEncode did not accept club.toJson() as a parameter:  it says that Map<String,dynamic>can't be assigned to the parameter type Object.function(dynamic)

Comment: oh i think i understand my mistake , i used JsonEncode instead of jsonEncode

Comment: I also see that you have a `String clubJsonToJson` method in your class, this should also work, if you try `String json = clubJsonToJson(club);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `String json = clubJsonToJson(club);`